# Quickly Coloring a Graph's Edges

Tags: graph

Suppose I am greedily assigning colors to edges of a graph `G = (V,E)` as follows,

1. Select an uncolored edge (u,v)
2. Identify the colors of all edges touching u and select the lowest unused color. Do the same for v.
3. Assign (u,v) the larger of the two colors.

A trivial way to perform step 2 is to check all colors `1,2,...` until coming across one that is not used by any edge touching `u`.  Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

You can also go through all the edges connected to `u`, eliminating colors that are used, and then pick the first unused color.

Comment: This algorithm is still linear in the number of neighbors to `u`. Is there anything asymptotically better?

Comment: It's pretty hard to beat linear in your case.  I think you'd have to look at all elements of some ONE thing: either ALL colors, or ALL neighbors of a node.  You can make the decision by comparing the average degree of your graph to the total number of colors, and pick the lowest one.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring#Exact_algorithms). Depending on what yout exactly want, you can have variations of the algorithms that can have a performance boost, wether you're looking one or all solutions.

Comment: I'm looking for an asymptotically fast way to color a graph's edges. I am not concerned with how far my solution is from optimal (within reason); thus the greedy approach.

Comment: Hm ... It seems difficult to find an alternative without fetching all nodes, to check edges. There would be a solution that would consist in reducing the number of edges to process by creating subgraphs but this process is way more complex than what you're doing.